# Images in a contenteditable div not deletable

Tags: image, contenteditable

I'm having a little inline editor which uses a contenteditable div. If you have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6psJ4/1/ is it possible to make the image not deletable?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div contenteditable="true">hi<img src="http://tinyw.in/BH9V" contenteditable="false"></div>
```

Worked for me on Firefox and Chrome, but it's not very usable - e.g. moving caret after the image wasn't possible without ecitable content after it.

AFAIK without custom delete key handler and bogus brs/spaces corrections it won't be possible to implement this as well as e.g. CKEDITOR.

Check this: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7529/_samples/placeholder.html